# Is it safe to marinate lamb for seven days?

Tags: lamb, marination

In his *[Le Gavroche cookbook](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/37489755-le-gavroche-cookbook)*, Michel Roux Jr. has a recipe for *Gigot d'agneau de sept heures* where he marinates the leg of lamb for **at least a week**.

However I see that e.g. the US Department of Health and Human Services, says that you should store a roast of lamb for **no more than 3-5 days** in your refrigerator in [their Cold Food Storage Chart](https://www.foodsafety.gov/food-safety-charts/cold-food-storage-charts).

Now, I feel that I should be able to trust both of these sources, but obviously I can't follow both of their advice. I kinda assume the storage chart might have some leeway, since the department *absolutely* do not want anyone to get sick from following their advice, so they add in a safety margin? Then again it'd suck if I gave my guests food poisoning, even if I followed the recipe of a food professional.

Are there any other considerations I should make? Could I get away with a somewhat shorter period of marinating the lamb? Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: The two sources might be making different assumptions about the source of the lamb, and what difference that makes to the risk of it going off. By comparison, note the famous difference between eggs in the USA which ordinarily have bleach-damaged shells which mean you have to refrigerate them, and eggs in Europe which are safe to store at room temperature.

Comment: Thanks, @VinceBowdren. It is common to store eggs in the fridge here in Norway, and what info I found on Norwegian food safety pages seems to agree with the US Department of Health. I am having trouble finding any other sources though, everything seems to lead back to the page linked in my question.